# performing a redirect in joomla1.5

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I have a situation in joomla in which I have to write the .htaccess file for redirects, such that if I type `http://mysite.com/fold2`, it should redirect to `http://mysite.com/fold1/fold2`,  but the URL should be like `mysite/fold2`.

Could you also tell me where is the best place in the .htaccess file to write this code?
Currently I think it is after:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: You can also do this from the Control Panel i.e cPanel. Simply go to the domain redirect option.

Comment: @Lodder there is no such option in Joomla 1.5!  applying 301 redirect using the .htaccess file will change the URL

Comment: what you can do (as a workaround) create folder2, and in it create an index.php that redirects to folder1/folder2/ with meta/HTTP-EQUIV or PHP header() ....

Comment: @alfisan, I didn't mean doing it from the Joomla 1.5 backend, I meant doing it from the host control panel ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect using PHP, then add this code you the index.php file:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://yourdomain.com/");
exit;
?>
```

If you want to redirect using .htaccess, then I believ this will work

```
Redirect 301 / http://yourdomain.com/
```

Hope this is what you are looking for